# Oracle Web Tool like PGAdmin for linux installation?

Tags: linux, oracle, user-interface

We're running serveral Oracle DBs hosted on AWS RDS. For security reasons, I can't connect to these DBs via Oracle SQL Developer, as the server are not exposed to the internet. I want to run a DB tool like PGAdmin on an EC2 instance and access this tool via webbrowser in order to manage my db, run sql queries etc.

Is there any tool out there you're aware of, fulfilling this needs?

Thanks!

Comment: I have dozens of Oracle databases hosted on AWS RDS and I can access them using SSH TUNNEL with SQL Developer, as long as I am logged on my corporate network. I guess those databases should be connected to your corporate network somehow.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertoHernandez! But SSH tunneling is not possible due to company internal restrictions. I'd need to run a tool within my vpc which I can access via port 443...

Comment: If you need a tool that you can access by 443, I would suggest SQL Developer Web over ORDS.  I can put an answer, if you want, on how to build it.

Comment: From our [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @JarMan - I think I've described the problem, haven't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working with OmniDB now - seems to do the trick.